# Add CSS style to a specific class via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got these lines of code and want to add them only to a specific div class. So if the background is dark it should be `filter: invert(1);` and when the background is brighter `filter: invert(0);`. How can I do that? Hope you can help me...I'm still at the very beginning of understanding js.

```
    function isDark( color ) {
    var match = /rgb\((\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)\)/.exec(color);
    return ( match[1] & 255 )
         + ( match[2] & 255 )
         + ( match[3] & 255 )
           < 3 * 256 / 2;
}

$('div').each(function() {console.log($(this).css("background-color"))
    $(this).css("filter", isDark($(this).css("background-color")) ? 'invert(1)' : 'invert(0)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition separately in an `if` `else` statement as below.

```
$('div').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  if (isDark(color)) {
    $(this).css("filter", 'invert(1)');
  } else {
    $(this).css("filter", 'invert(0)');
  }
});
```

**OR**

if you want a css `class` to be added, you can do it as below

```
$('div').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  if (isDark(color)) {
    $(this).addClass("inverted");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("not-inverted");
  }
});
```

in which the styles can be added for the new `class` in your CSS as below.

```
.inverted {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.not-inverted {
  filter: invert(0);
}
```

See the snippet below.

```js
function isDark(color) {
  var match = /rgb\((\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)\)/.exec(color);
  return (match[1] & 255) +
    (match[2] & 255) +
    (match[3] & 255) <
    3 * 256 / 2;
}
/* 
$('div').each(function() {console.log($(this).css("background-color"))
    $(this).css("filter", isDark($(this).css("background-color")) ? 'invert(1)' : 'invert(0)');
}); */

$('div').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  if (isDark(color)) {
    $(".logo").css("filter", 'invert(1)');
  } else {
    $(".logo").css("filter", 'invert(0)');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 400vh;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 20px;
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bicycle-shop-logo-design-vector_53876-40626.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.blabla {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50vh;
}

.blablabla {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50vh;
}

.blablablabla {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="blabla">test</div>
<div class="blablabla">test</div>
<div class="blablablabla">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did not really understand this. To clarify my problem here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfvays8g/1/)
I want to invert the logo or not when the background is dark or bright.

Comment: @jomawie is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/5whmLf14/3/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There were errors in your code..i'll update the answer with the modified one..

Comment: Thanks again for your help. What I am trying to achieve is just the inverting of the logo div or the logo itself, not the other ones. So if the background is black the logo should be white and if the background is white the logo should be black. 

So when someone is scrolling through a website with different background colors, the logo should always be visible whether the background is bright or dark.

Comment: Oh..ok..then, you can just replace `$(this).css("filter", 'invert(1)` with `$(".logo").css("filter", 'invert(1)`. Change it in the `else` part too..

Comment: May be that change too won't help you in achieving what you really want. You'll have to check(I suppose) which div comes as the background of the logo.

Comment: You want the logo to change automatically as the user scrolls and the background changes?  What should happen when the page is scrolled such that the logo is half on a dark background and half on light? You might have better lick using (for example) a dark logo with a light border, which as-is would be visible on both backgrounds

Comment: You probably can ask it as a new question in SO.